# CoreData Permanent IDs change when migrating store

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data

For an application I am developing, I need to refer to objects in my object store permanently. I use their `NSManagedObjectID` objects to do this, after calling `[NSManagedObjectContext obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:error:]` on the context they exist in.

However, when I migrate the store from an old version of the model to a newer one, these IDs seem to suddenly refer to completely different objects.

Is there any reason for the permanent IDs losing their 'permanence' after a store migration? From what I understand [from the docs,](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:error:)  these IDs should be permanent, and I don't understand why a very minor model migration (added properties to the objects) causes the 'permanent' IDs to suddenly refer to a completely different object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still have no clue why CoreData causes the object IDs to change on migrations, but I have a simple workaround:

Each of my objects have a property, "permanentId" in the MOC file. When I generate the `NSManagedObject` subclasses, I have them descend from a custom subclass, instead of directly `NSManagedObject`. This subclass automagically crates an `NSUUID` and sets it when the object is first created.

It's certainly not optimal, but it gets the job of giving objects an unique ID done.